# Read/write file only if it exists using fstream

Tags: c++, file

I'm handling a file using fstream, and I need to read and write to it. However, even using std::ios:in, the file continues to be created if it does not exist:

```
std::fstream file("myfile.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::app);
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (std::filesystem::exists("myfile.txt")) ...`

Comment: since removing `app` fixes issue vote to close as typo.

Comment: @MarekR i agree

Answer (score 1):

Read documentation carefully:

[std::basic_filebuf<CharT,Traits>::open - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open)

> The file is opened as if by calling [std::fopen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen) with the second argument (`mode`) determined as follows:
>
> | mode | openmode & ~ate | Action if file already exists | Action if file does not exist |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | "r" | in | Read from start | Failure to open |
> | "w" | out, out|trunc | Destroy contents | Create new |
> | "a" | app, out|app | Append to file | Create new |
> | "r+" | out|in | Read from start | Error |
> | "w+" | out|in|trunc | Destroy contents | Create new |
> | "a+" | out|in|app, in|app | Write to end | Create new |
> | "rb" | binary|in | Read from start | Failure to open |
> | "wb" | binary|out, binary|out|trunc | Destroy contents | Create new |
> | "ab" | binary|app, binary|out|app | Write to end | Create new |
> | "r+b" | binary|out|in | Read from start | Error |
> | "w+b" | binary|out|in|trunc | Destroy contents | Create new |
> | "a+b" | binary|out|in|app, binary|in|app | Write to end | Create new |

This should explain everything.

Just drop `app` flag and you done.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/p4vLC8ane9Ndh1gN

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches, you can do it the old way

```
std::fstream file("myfile.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out); // edited after comment
if (!file)
{
    // Can't open file for some reason
}
```

Or you can use standard library `std::filesystem::exists` introduced in C++17. [Read more about it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists).

```
if (std::filesystem::exists("myfile.txt")) { // Exists }
```

Remember that **file can exist but you can fail to interact with it** (read/write from/to it).

If needed:

```
g++ -std=c++17 yourFile.cpp -o output_executable_name
```

Comment: The first method is not effective as fstream creates the file if it doesn't exist. About the second method, I can't use c++ 17 due to some limitations. I thought the std::ios::in flag would be enough to only handle the file if it already exists. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: maybe open using r+ mode? look at @Marek R answer